# APEX 22.1.0 jquery radio groups not recognized when submitting the page

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I have an Application in APEX 22.1.0 with the Crimson-23 Theme on an oracle DB 19c which was originally developt in APEX 4.2.
There is a Table containing a radio group status column with three options in the body section of the page.
At page load always the first option is checked by default because of the SQL-Query which only loads rows with this option status.
I have added a Button with an dynamic action and jquery execution to set the Status from the first to the second option for all displayd rows on the page.

```
`$("td[headers='STATUS']").parent().each(function(){
  $(this).find("input[type='radio'][value='offen'][checked]").removeAttr("checked"); 
  $(this).find("input[type='radio'][value='interass']").attr("checked",true); 
  $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val('interass');
 });`
```

This button works fine as far I can see and changes the option but when I submit the page to update the Database Table no rows where updated. The Submit-Button works correct when I change the options for each row manually.

In the DevTools of the chrome browser is no difference in the html code between the two ways of changing the option.

Can anybody help please ?

Greets, Justy

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your issue in a freshly created app (22.1, universal theme) ?

Comment: No, not really, because in 22.1 universal theme there is no tabular form any more...I build up a new page with an interactive Grid and changed the radio group to select list (in 22.1 there is no reasonable way to put radio groups in a report or grid column). So I had to change the javascript as well.
Now its working.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. It's hard to debug old stuff because no one else can reproduce anymore